# How can i disable the checkbox when the scope value comes from the local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here i used the check box with angularjs. It can be trigger if the state is true;
That is $scope.seededDataAdhoc==1. if $scope.seededDataAdhoc==0 it should be disabled. It disabled when loads first tim. but when i load the data from local storage cant able to disable.

Likewise,
ng-click is also not working properly. I stuck here for a long time.
Can anyone please help on this.

Html code:

```
<label class="chkbox-holder" for="seededDatasAdhoc" ng-class="{'chck-active':seededDataAdhoc==1,'cursorprop':true}" ng-disabled="recurreadOnlyLoad==0"  ng-click="seededDataAdhoc != seededDataAdhoc;Recurring(seededDataAdhoc)">
<input type="checkbox" class="channelclass" name="seededDatasAdhoc" id="seededDatasAdhoc" ng-model="seededDataAdhoc" ng-checked="seededDataAdhoc==1" ng-disabled="recurreadOnlyLoad==0" parse-int="" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
<label for="seededDatasAdhoc"></label>Recurs Every Month</label>
```

In controller,

```
if($localStorage.recurryassign==true)
{
for(var i=0;i<data.ApplicationSettingsList.applicationSettings.length;i++)
{

if(data.ApplicationSettingsList.applicationSettings[i].name == "recurring")
{
$scope.seededDataAdhoc= data.ApplicationSettingsList.applicationSettings[i].userEditable;
if($scope.seededDataAdhoc==0)
{
$scope.recurreadOnly=0;   
$scope.recurreadOnlyLoad=0;
$scope.recurreadOnlySave=false; 
}
else
{
$scope.recurreadOnly=1;   
$scope.recurreadOnlyLoad=1;
$scope.recurreadOnlySave=true;    
}

}

}
}
else
{
$scope.seededDataAdhoc=$localStorage.seededDataAdhoc;
if($scope.seededDataAdhoc==0)
{
$scope.recurreadOnly=0;   
//cant able to assign this scope to html(in ngdisabled)
$scope.recurreadOnlyLoad=0;
$scope.recurreadOnlySave=false; 
}
else
{
$scope.recurreadOnly=1;   
$scope.recurreadOnlyLoad=1;
$scope.recurreadOnlySave=true;    
}
}
```

Comment: Can u create a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9mdytqer/